# VirtualBox Kernel driver not installed, key rejected

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

How can I load the VirtualBox kernel module with `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` when the key is rejected?

Since today's update on Ubuntu 23.10 I am no longer able to start any virtual machine on VirtualBox. Doing so I get this error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel
module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.
```

So I installed `virtualbox-dkms` and then tried to run `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`. Doing so I get this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Key was rejected by service
```

My pretty basic daily update looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
sudo snap refresh
```